# Display inline drops content down a line

Tags: html, css

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/aeR7y/23/

I am wondering how to get my header list to sit on the same line as the header, rather than dropping down. This is the code I am using for the list:

```
#header li {
    display: inline;
}
```

I know it's basic but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display everything inline,

```
#header li, #header ul, h1 {
    display: inline;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aeR7y/26/

Answer (score 2):

Try this.
This will make your li be inline with header content. now you can set its position as you want.

```
#header h1,#header ul, #header ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aeR7y/25/)